# Assign TO_CHAR value to VARCHAR fails

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting number or value error in below function

At the following  line

```
acutalStartTime:=TO_CHAR (startTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd ');
```

could anyone tell me what could be wrong, can anyone also let me know if I can write this one better way?

```
create or replace function dateDiff 
  ( changeInStartTime out varchar2,acutalStartTime out varchar2 )
RETURN timestamp
IS
  startTime timestamp;
  v_start   timestamp;
  diffdays number;
  findiff  BOOLEAN;
  diff number;

  cursor c1 is
  SELECT sometime from sometable;

BEGIN

  changeInStartTime:='false';
    v_start := TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP) + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'second'); 
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into startTime;

      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('value of query ' ||startTime);

    if c1%notfound then
        startTime := TO_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00:00.001','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss .ff3');
 findiff:=false;

   else findiff:=true;
    end if;

 --Dbms_Output.Put_Line('should we find diff' || findiff);

    if findiff then
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_start ' || v_start);
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('startTime ' || startTime);

         diff :=trunc(v_start) - trunc(startTime) ;
      --diffdays:=extract(day from diff);

      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('diff ' || diff);
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('diffdays ' || diffdays);

    if diff > 1 then
        changeInStartTime:='true';

        startTime:=TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP-diff ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'second'); 
    else startTime:=v_start;
    end if;

    close c1;

  end if;
  acutalStartTime:=TO_CHAR (startTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd ');
    RETURN startTime;

    EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: Can you post what the actual ORA error is that you are getting?

Comment: RA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Comment: also, dbms_output the real value of startTime just before that

Comment: Is it really spelled "acutal"?

Comment: Why are you using an exception handler to just provide a custom format to the error code? Just let the system raise the error itself.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the space at the end of the literal?

```
acutalStartTime:=TO_CHAR (startTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd ');
--                                              ^
```

That makes the returned value 11 characters long, and perhaps the variable in the calling code  is defined as VARCHAR2(10)?

Comment: @hol: Yes, but my point was that it makes a string of 11 characters, which *might* have been 1 more than was expected.  It *looks* like a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code to call `dateDiff`:

```
declare
  datum varchar2(20);
  cist varchar2(20);
  ret timestamp;
begin
  ret := dateDiff(cist, datum);
end;
/
```

The anonymous code block completed without errors.

The problem must be in the calling code. Check that the parameters are of type `varchar2` and large enough to hold the return values.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you get this error message:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 22
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

This can be reproduced if the `VARCHAR2` variable of the calling program is too short.

Here is a testprogram demonstrating it:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  diff            number := 1;
  startTime       timestamp;    
  acutalStartTime varchar2(100);
  shortStartTime  varchar2(1);
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Start');

  startTime:=TRUNC (SYSTIMESTAMP-diff ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'second');
  dbms_output.put_line(startTime);

  -- WORKS BECAUSE VARCHAR IS LONG ENOUGH 
  ----------------------------
  acutalStartTime:=TO_CHAR (startTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd ');
  dbms_output.put_line(acutalStartTime);

  -- CRASHING STATEMENT
  ----------------------------
  shortStartTime:=TO_CHAR (startTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd ');
  dbms_output.put_line(shortStartTime);

  dbms_output.put_line('End');
end;
/
```

Output:

```
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 19
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Start
10-JUN-13 12.00.01.000000 AM
2013-06-10
```

Make sure your calling routine has a long enough `VARCHAR2`

Comment: I was finally able to solve the issue  the proc from where i was calling i was sending timestamp but the function was expecting varchar2 but still it dint showed the error it should have

Comment: @Ashwin Excellent. Accept an answer that was correct or post your own answer and accept it if none are really correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using OUT parameters in a function is specifically called out as bad practice in the Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#autoId2).

> > Do not use OUT and IN OUT for function parameters. Ideally, a function takes zero or more parameters and returns a single value. A function with IN OUT parameters returns multiple values and has side effects.

So you might like to work out whether this is a function or a procedure first.

Comment: I am actually calling the function from SP , my the out param in function is also out param in SP i think it something to do with varchar2 defination in sp for  out params we cannot specificy the actual size i.e varchar2(64)

Comment: Regarding using out parameter how else can i return more then value

Comment: With a procedure, or a pipelined function.

Comment: thank you, is there a way to specify the varchar2 byte details

Comment: You can't specify the size of a varchar2 as part of the argument definition or in a RETURN clause from within the pl/sql program block. Doing so would only change the location where an error is raised -- to fix the problem you have to prevent your code from assigning a value to a variable that cannot hold it.

Comment: So what is the solution to my problem i did convert it to proc but no diff

Comment: Take out the exception handling and re-post the code, including the code that calls it and the complete error stack that you receive.